# CloudBoost : Unable to log out (android / Java)

Tags: java, android, mbaas, cloudboost

I tried logging out on my App using Android. I used the function `logOut` of the class `CloudUser`, but I ended up getting a `Bad Request Response`.

This is how I call the `logOut`-Method

```
CloudUserHelper.logOut(MainFreeDaysListActivity.this, CloudUser.getcurrentUser());
```

and this is the `logOut`-Method.

```
public static void logOut(final MainFreeDaysListActivity activity,final CloudUser user){
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try{
                user.logOut(new CloudUserCallback()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void done(CloudUser user, CloudException e) throws CloudException
                    {
                        if (e == null){
                            activity.backToWelcome();
                            activity.finish();
                        }
                        else{
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            catch(CloudException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

And finally, this is the error that I'm getting whenever I am trying to log out.

```
03-14 10:35:33.090 16000-17106/com.example.aetitia.freedays W/System.err: io.cloudboost.CloudException: {"message":"You are not logged in"}
03-14 10:35:33.091 16000-17106/com.example.aetitia.freedays W/System.err:     at io.cloudboost.CloudUser.logOut(CloudUser.java:264)
03-14 10:35:33.091 16000-17106/com.example.aetitia.freedays W/System.err:     at com.example.aetitia.freedays.CloudUserHelper$3.run(CloudUserHelper.java:104)
03-14 10:35:33.091 16000-17106/com.example.aetitia.freedays W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

What could be the reason ?

Comment: Hello! Please take the [tour] and try to understand the concept of a [MCVE]. That helps you since your question will be more likely to attract answers that way, and it helps us to understand your problem.

Comment: My Question is  better like this?

Comment: Yes, it is, good job :) I edited a bit, too. Should be good to go now.

Answer (score 2):

That error is a bug in `CloudBoost JavaSDK-1.0.2` and the earlier builds of `1.0.3`. Please clone the latest sources from [github](https://github.com/CloudBoost/JavaSDK) or get the latest release on [maven](https://github.com/CloudBoost/JavaSDK).
 Additionally, I have just created an android `CloudUser demo`, available on [github](https://github.com/egimaben/CloudUser-demo) which covers `signup`, `login`, `logout` plus the latest APIs: `changePassword` and `resetPassword`.